# Ubuntu shows Ethernet is connected but takes too long for internet to start working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

When connecting over Ethernet, it usually takes about 10-15 minutes for internet connection to work, even though the arrows show the Ethernet is connected as soon as I boot up. This issue is not present on the same machine with the same Ethernet when using Windows.

Sometimes the internet does start working instantly on boot, but more often than not, it takes 10 minutes or more. The connection over Ethernet is secured with certificate and username & password (specifically 802.1x, EAP-TTLS, PAP).

When the internet starts working, it works flawlessly. It is not cutting out or anything like that. It's also worth mentioning that it will eventually start working every time -- it's just that it takes 10 minutes or more.

I noticed that, when the connection is not working, I'm unable to get my IP when issuing `curl ifconfig.me`. The command returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.me`.

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
# The primary network interface
#auto enp0s3
#iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Also, I am not sure if it is relevant, but, if I am connecting to the same network over Wi-Fi, it works as expected (starts working instantly).

I'm happy to provide contents of more files if needed.

Comment: If Ubutnu, NetworkManager should be in control. What does `nmcli` say during those 10-15 min intervals?